# Colon in AppDomain causing problems with log4net.Util.PatternString

Tags: nunit, resharper, log4net, appdomain, gallio

I'm using ReSharper 7.1.1, NUnit 2.6.0 and log4net 1.2.10.

In my log4net configuration I have a RollingFileAppender:

```
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%appdomain.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{ISO8601} %-5level - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
    <threshold value="ALL" />
</appender>
```

I get the following error when my unit test code runs:

```
log4net:ERROR XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Could not create Appender [file] of type [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]. Reported error follows.
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.ConvertToFullPath(String path)
   at log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.ActivateOptions()
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
```

The reason for this is that the log4net `%appdomain` value is taken from the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName value, which is:

```
IsolatedAppDomainHost: MyProject.Tests
```

Because this AppDomain name contains a colon, it's unable to convert it to a filename, i.e. %`appdomain.log` becomes `IsolatedAppDomainHost: MyProject.Tests.log`

I'm looking for some suggestions for a workaround:

- Can I override the AppDomain value somehow, just for unit test projects?
- Can I modify the `log4net.Util.PatternString` so that it strips out the colon?
- Can I configure the ReSharper test runner to avoid this problem?
- Has this been fixed in newer versions of any of the tools I'm using? I couldn't find any mentions of this problem elsewhere.

If not, I can try and submit a pull request to either Gallio or log4net - though I'm not sure which is "at fault" in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public class SafeRollingFileAppender : log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
{
    public override string File
    {
        get { return base.File; }
        set 
        {
            //remove that pesky colon
            string newValue = value.Replace(":", "");

            //now do some general purpose cleanup
            string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(newValue);
            string file = Path.GetFileName(newValue);

            string dirRegexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
            Regex dr = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(dirRegexSearch)));
            string newDir = dr.Replace(dir, "");

            string fileRegexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
            Regex fr = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(fileRegexSearch)));
            string newFile = fr.Replace(file, "");

            base.File = Path.Combine(newDir, newFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks. I've made a minor correction to the code to make the File an override (not virtual).

Answer (score 2):

> Can I modify the log4net.Util.PatternString so that it strips out the colon?

Probably not a good idea as this could end up striping out colons in other places.

You could download the log4net source code and add some validation on the file property, but if you don't want to do that, you could implement your own Appender which overrides the File property , something like

```
public class SaferRollingFileAppender : log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender
{     
    virtual public string File
    {
        get { return base.File ; }
        set { base.File = value.Replace(":",""); }
    }
}
```

Would obviously be better if this fully validated the name rather than just checking for the colon. (Originally thought that it would be a matter of removing all Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() and Path.GetInvalidPathChars() characters, but it's not as simple as that, so I leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

Downside would be that anything that uses your class needs to be able to find the assembly it is contained it.